# Text in resource file is not displaying correctly in Chinese

Tags: asp.net, localization, cjk, resource-files

I have a website that is written in asp.net where the text is resourced in resource files.  I am able to successfully view the correct characters for all (Spanish, German, Arabic, Korean, etc) languages except Chinese.  When I change my browser to Chinese (any version) I get weird characters displayed.  I have Chinese fonts installed and have tried changing encoding but nothing seems to work.  This is happening in both IE9 and FF9.

Ex:

English - Progress

Chinese (in resource file) - 進度

Display in browser - è¿›ç¨‹

Any help would be appreciated,

Matt

Comment: What is the encoding of the Chinese .resx file?

Comment: Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001

Comment: What is the encoding of the Web page? Do you have a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` tag?

Comment: FYI...I am seeing the same weird characters in the actual resource file in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes....content="text/html; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see weird characters in the .resx file when you edit it in Visual Studio, that means the file itself is corrupt. Fix the errors and the text should show up properly in the browser.